# Express.js proxy pipe translate XML to JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, json, express, proxy

For my front-end (angular) app, I need to connect to an external API, which does not support CORS.

So my way around this is to have a simple proxy in Node.JS / Express.JS to pass the requests. The additional benefit is that I can set my api-credentials at proxy level, and don't have to pass them to the front-end where the user might steal/abuse them.

This is all working perfectly.

Here's the code, for the record:

```
var request = require('request');
var config = require('./config');

var url   = config.api.endpoint;
var uname = config.api.uname;
var pword = config.api.pword;
var headers = {
    "Authorization" : 'Basic ' + new Buffer(uname + ':' + pword).toString('base64'),
    "Accept" : "application/json"
};

exports.get = function(req, res) {
  var api_url = url+req.url;
  var r = request({url: api_url, headers: headers});
  req.pipe(r).pipe(res);
};
```

The API-endpoint I have to use has XML as only output format. So I use xml2js on the front-end to convert the XML reponse to JSON.

This is also working great, but I would like to lighten the load for the client, and do the XML -> JSON parsing step on the server.

I assume I will have to create something like:

```
req.pipe(r).pipe(<convert_xml_to_json>).pipe(res);
```

But I don't have any idea how do create something like that.

So basically I'm looking to create an XML to JSON proxy as a layer on top of an already existing API.

There are a lot of questions on SO regarding "how do I make a proxy" and "how do I convert XML to JSON" but I couldn't find any that combine the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use [transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) and for xml to json conversion you need some library i use this [xml2json](https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json)

..then u use it like this (simplified but it should work with request too)

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var parser = require('xml2json');
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;


function xmlParser () {
  var transform = new Transform();
  transform._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
    chunk = parser.toJson(chunk.toString())
    console.log(chunk);
    this.push(chunk);
    done();
  };

  transform.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  return transform;
}

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/data.xml');
  stream.pipe(xmlParser()).pipe(res);
});
server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Had some trouble getting it to work, but then I realized I was using xml2js instead of xml2json. After switching it, everything works.

Comment: Well-written answer.. Great.!!